# 3 seconds for pressing the back button

Tags: java, android

I tried to write an app, in which first user see splashcreen and after 3 seconds he is moved to mainscreen. If user press back button during this 3 seconds, he will stay on splashscreen

I tried few methods of delay ( like stopping the thread or some stupid for loop) but i couldn't do my task ( changing screen after 3 sec and not if back was pressed)

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean checkerbool=true;// check if its in the 3s loop
    boolean background=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
         Handler handler=new Handler();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkerbool=false;
            }
            }, 3000);
      if(background) setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(checkerbool) background=false;

            return true;
        }


        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

But after starting an app it jumps directly into mainscreen
Working project will be when user is moved to diffrent screen after 3s and if user press the button back, he will stay at splashscreen

Comment: Can make it clear! Are you looking for a solution to implement splash screen right?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to implement changeing screen after delay

Answer (score 2):

override the `onBackPressed` method :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    checkerbool = true;
}
```

Change  :

```
boolean checkerbool=false;
```

Finally :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!checkerbool)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
 }, 3000);
```

You need to move `setContent` to the `run` method, because `postDelayed` will no block the main thread it just post execute what is inside `run` after the time you mention(3000).

Comment: It doesn't matter if i use onBackPressed or onKeyDown, because background is still changeing instantly to mainscreen